# Traveler's note

Tags: riddle, wordplay

There was once a traveler that wanted to travel the globe, and one day he sent me this weirdly written note

```
ME IN LA, CA, OK?
```

Where did the traveler go?

Comment: Gung jbhyq cebonoyl or uneqre sbe fbzrbar va n qvssrerag pbhagel, ohg nf fbzrbar jub vf n HF pvgvmra, vg'f gevivny ng orfg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traveler went to

> Maine (ME), Indiana (IN), Louisiana (LA), California (CA), and Oklahoma (OK).

Comment: Made this one pretty easy